# finding a pattern, adding newlines after it in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to add two newlines after a pattern in a text file and then return the corrected file, without removing the pattern. So far I've only succeeded in replacing the pattern:

```
def cleanTxt (list_path, results_path):

    with open (list_path,'r') as myText:
        data = myText.read()
        with open (results_path, 'w') as results_file:
            new = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]','\n\n', data)
            results_file.write(new)

            results_file.close()
```

I also tried other approaches, e.g.

```
for pattern in re.findall(r'\[{1,3}\:\[{1,3}\:\[{1,3}\]',myText):
```

but was getting nowhere with that.

How can I add the newlines while leaving the pattern in the text file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace the match *with the matched text itself*, plus the two newlines.  In Python, `\g<0>` in the replacement text represents the entire original match (note: this is an area of disagreement between different languages' regex implementations).  So try:

```
new = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', r'\g<0>\n\n', data)
```

Comment: beautiful. totally worked. Thanks, didn't know about that matching pattern for the entire original match.

Answer (score 0):

here is your code with a few modifications to make it work:

```
def cleanTxt (list_path, results_path):

    with open(list_path, 'r') as myText:
        data = myText.read()
        with open(results_path, 'w') as results_file:
            newArr = re.split(r'\[.*?\]', data)
            patt = re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', data)
            new = ""
            for i in xrange(len(patt)):
                new += newArr[i]
                new += patt[i]
                new += "\n\n"
            new += newArr[-1]
            results_file.write(new)

            results_file.close()
```